# AutoCompleteExtender not working in DotNetNuke

Tags: autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 6.0 and VS2008 AjaxControl Tool kit 3.5

I am trying to add ASP.NET AutoCompleteExtender to a text box in one of my modules in DNN.

As far as I know the AutoCompleteExtender works only through a webservice.

I've added a webservice, but I can not get the AutoCompleteExtender to work, I get no errors but the webservice never gets invoked, What am I missing or how can I get the ASP.NET AutoCompleteExtender to work?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the following problem:

**ERROR MSG:** Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script.

Try to put [ScriptService] as a definition of your web service class.
Example:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://dnndev/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class BusinessDataProvider : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]        
    public string[] GetSpecificListOfContributors(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        return ContributorController.GetSpecificListOfContributors(prefixText, count);
    }
}
```

I hope this one will help you.

Best,